# get object using has many through with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5.

Here I am using has many through with polymorphic

Tables are

```
categories, category_items, albums
```

Models are

```
Category, CategoryItem, Album
```

app/model/album.rb

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_items, as: :category_itemable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :category_items
end
```

app/model/category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

app/model/category_item.rb

```
class CategoryItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category_itemable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
  belongs_to :category, optional: true
end
```

I am able to get categories of a specific album through association. but now I need to get albums of a specific category.

Please find the solution and make sure don't use method. association should be clean and simple

Many Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `has_many` association for `album` in `Category` model

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :albums, through: :category_items, source: :category_itemable, source_type: 'Album'
end
```

And now you will be able to get albums for a category instance